AttributeError: module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'TextSymbol'
I am trying to geocode using ArcPy Python script in ArcGIS Pro and I keep getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python Scripting for
ArcGIS\finalproject\finalpython\Gecoding.py", line 10, in 
text_symbol = arcpy.mp.TextSymbol() AttributeError: module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'TextSymbol'

Here is the full script
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python Scripting for ArcGIS\finalproject\finalproject.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
road_dataset = r"C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Harford_County_Maintained_Roads_-3767853144656662417.csv"
road_name_field = "MD_iMAP_Composite_Locator"
output_point_fc = r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python Scripting for ArcGIS\finalproject\finalproject.gdb\Harford_County_GeocodeAddres"
geocode_result = r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python Scripting for ArcGIS\finalproject\finalproject.gdb\Harford_County_GeocodeAddres"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(geocode_result, "RoadNamePoints_layer")
label_expression = "[" + road_name_field + "]"
text_symbol = arcpy.mp.TextSymbol()
text_symbol.font.size = 10
text_symbol.font.family = "Arial"
label_placement = "NO_OVERLAP"
label_point_placement = "UPPER_RIGHT"
arcpy.mp.AddLayer(arcpy.mp.ListDataFrames(arcpy.mp.MapDocument("CURRENT"))[0], "RoadNamePoints_layer", "AUTO_ARRANGE")
for lyr in arcpy.mp.ListLayers(arcpy.mp.MapDocument("CURRENT")):
    if lyr.name == "RoadNamePoints_layer":
        lblClass = lyr.listLabelClasses()[0]
        lblClass.expression = label_expression
        lblClass.textSymbol = text_symbol
        lblClass.placement = label_placement
        lblClass.position = label_point_placement
        arcpy.mp.refreshTOC()
        arcpy.mp.refreshActiveView()
        print("Geocoding and labeling completed.")


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python Scripting for ArcGIS\finalproject\finalpython\Gecoding.py", line 10, in 
text_symbol = arcpy.mp.TextSymbol()
AttributeError: module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'TextSymbol'

That is correct, arcpy.mp has no attribute TextSymbol, have a look at https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/alphabeticallistofclasses.htm and you'll find it's not in the list. I did find something that may help in CIM https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm and search for labelClasses then call setDefinition on your label class theoretically, I've not done it myself. The only reference I can find for TextSymbol in ArcGIS belongs to an API other than arcpy.

well i need to use an arcpy for this project , if the code needs to be removed but still operates i don't mind that

You'll need to remove that, also lblClass.textSymbol doesn't exist, get rid of all those and replace with setDefinition (if it works), have a close look at the label class object (link in previous comment) to see what options are available. If not you can create a template feature class with the labels and symbology already defined, add the layer to the map and change the data source https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm as if the layer is broken.

You're trying to use code based on ArcMap arcpy. You will also get an error with arcpy.mp.MapDocument which doesn't exist in Pro. ArcGIS Pro arcpy is different from ArcMap. See "Migrating from arcpy.mapping to ArcGIS Pro"

So basically this whole code is not running because the attributes don't match with arcgis pro

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/textelement-class.htm

Hello everyone Thank you for your help my code is working now
